# Activity tracker that is worn around the neck

Tags: tracking-devices

I use Fitbit charge HR.
I don't like this because anxious to hit the keyboard when typing.
So I want other activity tracker.

Requirements:

1. It is an activity tracker that does not attach to the wrist.
2. It is able to measure heart rate or pulse.
3. It provides Web Application.
4. It provides REST API.